# Returned JSON, write with Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Hy all!

I have a little problem. I tried to write an ajax post to get values from a database, and it's  returning format is an a JSON object.
How can I get the key, and value pairs from it?

the jquery which sending the ajax:

function getTableData() {

```
        $.post('loader.php',getGetStr(),function(data){
                        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                        console.log(json);
        });
    }
```

The console.log output is:

```
Object {query-data: Array[3]}
query-data: Array[3]
0: Object
buy_type: "kiado"
condition_type: "uj"
district: "1"
heat_type: "cirko"
id: "1"
lift_type: "all"
parking_type: "all"
price_max: "22"
price_min: "10"
prop_type: "lakas"
room_max: "3"
room_min: "1"
street: "all"
uid: "3"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
2: Object
length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
```

The php code wich select the rights things, and return the data to the ajax:

```
$ordering = array ("buy_type " . $_POST['buyType'],"prop_type     ".$_POST['propertyType'],"district ".$_POST['disctrict'],
                    "street ".$_POST['street'],"room_min     ".$_POST['roomMin'],"room_max ".$_POST['roomMax'],
                    "price_min ".$_POST['priceMin'],"price_max     ".$_POST['priceMax'],"condition_type ".$_POST['conditionType'],"heat_type ".$_POST['heatType'],"lift_type ".$_POST['liftType'],"parking_type ".$_POST['parkingType']);

$user=$_SESSION["user"];
$whois = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid='.$mysqli->real_escape_string($user).' ');
$who = $whois->fetch_assoc();

switch($who['user_title']){
    case '0':
        $res=$mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM searches WHERE uid='.$mysqli->real_escape_string($user).' 
                ORDER BY '.$mysqli->real_escape_string($ordering[0]).',
                        '.$mysqli->real_escape_string($ordering[1]).',
                        '.$mysqli->real_escape_string($ordering[2]).',
                        '.$mysqli->real_escape_string($ordering[3]).',
                        '.$mysqli->real_escape_string($ordering[4]).',
                        '.$mysqli->real_escape_string($ordering[5]).',
                        '.$mysqli->real_escape_string($ordering[6]).',
                        '.$mysqli->real_escape_string($ordering[7]).',
                        '.$mysqli->real_escape_string($ordering[8]).',
                        '.$mysqli->real_escape_string($ordering[9]).',
                        '.$mysqli->real_escape_string($ordering[10]).',
                        '.$mysqli->real_escape_string($ordering[11]).'
                  ') or die($mysqli->error);
        while($ki=$res->fetch_assoc()){
            $tomb[] = $ki;
        }
        $tomb = array("query-data"=>$tomb);
        echo json_encode($tomb);
```

can anybody help to me to write these values to a table?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: It's just an ordinary Javascript object, you can access it with `json['query-data']`. This is an array you can iterate over.

Comment: Just an advice, pass an extra argument to `$.post` as `json` so you dont need to use `$.parseJSON`. `ie: $.post(url,params,callback,'json')`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this.

**UPDATED:**

```
$.post( 'loader.php', getGetStr(), function( data ) {
  if ( !data || !data['query-data'] ) {
    // invalid json string, so dont process
    return;
  }
  data  = data['query-data'];
  // create the table
  var table = $("<table />").html('<thead></thead><tbody></tbody>');
  // inserted table head cols?
  var thead = false;

  // loop through 'query-data'
  for( i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
    // append 'tr' element to 'tbody'
    var tr1 = $("<tr />").appendTo( table.find("tbody") );
    if ( !thead ) {
      // if not finished creating table head cols, then append 'tr' elemnts to thead
      var tr2 = $("<tr />").appendTo( table.find("thead") );
    }
    // loop if its an object
    if ( typeof data[i] === "object" ) {
      for( j in data[i] ) {
        if ( !thead ) {
          // if not finished creating table head cols, then append 'th' elements to thead
          $("<th />").html( j ).appendTo( tr2 );
        }
        // insert our real dat to table rows
        $("<td />").html( data[i][j] ).appendTo( tr1 );
      }
      // we finished creating table head cols
      thead = true;
    }
  }

  // append the table to whatever element you want,
  // you can also use $("body").html( table );
  table.appendTo( $("body") );
}, "json" );
```

Comment: But how can I write to table from these query??

Comment: Don't use `for .. in` to iterate over an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through an object like this:

**without** inherited properties from it's prototype

```
for( i in json ) {
    if ( json.hasOwnProperty( i ) ) {
        console.log( i, json[ i ] );
    }
}
```

**with** inherited properties from it's prototype

```
for( i in json ) {
    console.log( i, json[ i ] );
}
```

`i` is the key and `json[ i ]` is the value.

Comment: but the output dosen't different. how can I get the values like key, value ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to iterate query-data using  console.log(json.query-data[0]); or foreach;

Write a dynamic html table to display.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the principle for printing a table

```
function printRow(item){
    var html = "<tr>";
    for(var key in item){
        html += "<td>"+key+"</td><td>"+item[key]+"</td">;
    }
    html += "</tr>";
    return html;
}
$.post('loader.php',getGetStr(),function(data){
    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(json);
    for(var key in json['query-data']){
        var item = json['query-data'][key];
        var html = "<table>";
        html += printRow(item);
        html += "</table>";
    }
});
```